# How to start daemon from buildbot ShellCommand

Tags: linux, daemon, buildbot

I have an application, it runs as a daemon using the [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) function.

```c
int pid = fork();
if (pid != 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

If run it from the console, everything works correctly. but if buildbot does this using the ShellCommand, then it waits for the daemon to terminate.

How it is done... `qmake` generates a `MakeFile` with the target `release`, the target `release` in turn launches my daemon.

```qmake
release.commands = daemon
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += release
```

If you run `qmake` with the console then `make release`, then everything works correctly.

```python
steps.ShellCommand(
    command= ['make', 'release'],
    doStepIf = lambda step : isRelease(step) and  isLinux(step),
    name = 'release Linux',
    haltOnFailure = True,
    description = 'release project',
)
```

Tell me how to run the daemon from BuildBot?

Comment: you fork call is __really__ fishy, the father of a process _must_ wait for its sibling, which is not what you do there. This will create zombie processes.

Comment: This is not a zombie process, the child process is controlled by the api command.
This method is described [here](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html)

Comment: Can you launch your daemon by `python3 -c 'import subprocess;subprocess.Popen(["make", "release"])'` from the console